# Pythonic way not working with list

Tags: python, list

I have a seemingly simple problem, but I the code that I believe should solve it is not behaving as expected -- but a less elegant code that I find functionally equivalent behaves as expected. Can you help me understand?

The task: create a list, drop a specific value. 
The specific usecase is that I am dropping a specific list of columns of pd.df, but that is not the part I want to focus on. It's that I seem to be unable to do it in a nice, pythonic single-line operation.

What I think should work:

```
result = list(df.columns).remove(x)
```

This results in object of type 'NoneType'

However, the following works fine:

```
result = list(df.columns)
result.remove(X)
```

These look functionally equivalent to me -- but the top approach is clearer and preferred, but it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are definitely not functionally equivalent.

1. The first piece of code puts the result of the last called method into result, so whatever `remove` returns. `remove` always returns None since it returns nothing.
2. The second piece of code puts the list into result, then removes from the list (which is already stored in result) the item. You are discarding the return of `remove`, as you should. **The equivalent and wrong thing to do** would be:

:

```
result = list(df.columns)
result = result.remove(X)
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `remove` changes the list, and does not return a new one, so you can't chain it.

What about the following way?

```
result = [item for item in df.columns if item != x]
```

Please note that this code is not **exactly** equivalent to the one you provided, as it will remove all occurrences of `x`, not just the first one as with `remove(x)`.

Comment: oh -- did not find that info. Thanks

Comment: @dozyaustin next time check `help(list.remove)`

Comment: Note, this isn't actually equivalent to `result = list(df.columns); result.remove(X)`

Comment: Yeah, with `remove(x)` only one occurrence of `x` is removed.

Comment: Also, `remove()` will remove the element in-place, while the list comprehension creates a new copy of the list.

Comment: @ErikCederstrand a new list was already created with `list(df.columns)`.

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of code are not really equivalent. In the second one, the variable `result` holds your list. You then call `remove` on that list, and the element is removed. So far so good.

In the first piece of code you try to assign the return value of `remove()` to result, so this would be the same as:

```
result = list(df.columns)
result = result.remove(X)
```

And since `remove` has no return value, the result will be `NoneType`.